# how can I add "_" symbol in paste() for at the first two place

Tags: r, paste

```
paste("plot", "var","m",".pdf", sep = "_")
#[1] "plot_var_m_.pdf"
```

however, I want an output of `plot_var_m.pdf` (the last "_" is not wanted)
How should I change my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
paste(paste("plot", "var","m", sep = "_"),"pdf", sep = ".")
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sprintf`

```
sprintf("%s.pdf", paste("plot", "var", "m", sep="_"))
#[1] "plot_var_m.pdf"
```

---

Another option is `sub`

```
sub("_([^_]+)$", ".\\1", "plot_var_m_pdf")
#[1] "plot_var_m.pdf"
```

Comment: Beat me - or even `sprintf("%s_%s_%s%s", "plot", "var","m",".pdf")`

Answer (score 1):

Another way is we can remove the last `_` which is extra and not needed by

```
sub("(.*)\\_", "\\1", paste("plot", "var","m",".pdf", sep = "_"))
#[1] "plot_var_m.pdf"
```

Answer (score 1):

If those variable names are constant, you can also just do:

```
paste("plot_", "var_","m",".pdf", sep = "")
```

Or, if the names are changing:

```
paste("plot","_","var","_","m",".pdf",sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way (adding another layer on top of your code to remove all unwanted `_.` patterns by `.`):

```
gsub('_\\.', '\\.', paste("plot", "var","m",".pdf", sep = "_"))
# [1] "plot_var_m.pdf"
```